# Passing argument based on condition

Tags: go

I have a function that accepts varargs.

```
func MyFunc(strs ...string)
MyFunc(entry1, entry2, entry3)
```

My usecase is to pass one of the entry based on some condition.

Is it possible to have something like this with similar effect as below (so that I don't need to have an if-else calling MyFunc inside both):

```
MyFunc(entry1, if(condition)entry2, entry3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just prepare arguments as slice:

```golang
myArgs := []string{"entry1"}
if (condition) {
    myArgs = append(myArgs, "entry2")
}
myArgs = append(myArgs, "entry3")
```

and then call variadic function using your slice:

```golang
MyFunc(myArgs...)
```

Comment: 26 seconds late :) [The playground](https://go.dev/play/p/HdfdX2T5Qr7)

Comment: Why should one build/allocate a slice when the exact number of arguments is known? Go favours explicit code. Just write `if (cond) { f(arg1, arg3) } else { f(arg1, arg2, arg3} }` please.

Comment: @PascaldeKloe while I'd do that OP specifically asked if its possible to not do that, citing: "_so that I don't need to have an if-else calling MyFunc inside both_"

Comment: Fair enough @blami. The question did not require the alternative to be shorter explicitly. 